# Run OpenJMS server as an embedded application

Tags: java, openjms

I have an application that needs to also be the JMS server (broker).  So I would like to start within the same JVM the OpenJMS server.  I have loosely read that this is possible, but I could not find any examples or explanation on the http://openjms.sourceforge.net site or anywhere else for that matter.

Has anyone done this, how simple is it?  I know with HornetQ it is very simple but we want to remain with OpenJMS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes in HornetQ you could start an embedded jms server with only two line of code and a configuration xml.

Being that HornetQ is POJO based and opensource, why don't you choose it?

Piero.

You could also check more details on embedding HornetQ in the new HornetQ book

[www.amazon.com/dp/1849518408/?tag=packtpubli-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849518408)